# How to remove a special character in a single word/variable

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $var= "File/";
$var=~ /\w/;
print "$var";
```

The expected outcome is File but it doest work.

Comment: what is the output of the code ?

Comment: The output is an empty string.

Comment: @Joey , https://stackoverflow.com/tour see how when people answer question

Comment: The output is not an empty string. It is the string "File/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. The match operator (`m/.../` or, as you are using it, `/.../`) is for *matching* text. It tells you if your string matches the regex. It does not change the string at all.

What you want is the substitution operator (`s/.../.../`). That replaces the matching text with something new. In this case, you want to replace the matching string with an empty string.

```
my $var= "File/";
$var =~ s/\w//; # // is an empty replacement string
print "$var";
```

But that's still not correct as `\w` matches any word character (alphanumerics and the underscore). What you need is `\W`, which matches any non-word character.

```
my $var= "File/";
$var =~ s/\W//; # // is an empty replacement string
print "$var";
```

Comment: @simbabque: Thanks. Sorry I couldn't be there. See you at the LPW?

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Answer (score 1):

You almost there, just using `\W` instead of `\w`.

```
my $var= "File/";

$var =~ s/\W+//g;

print "$var";
```

Output is File

Comment: You also silently replaced `/.../` with `s/.../.../`. That's a rather important change.